Permission handler not giving any response at all
Hey I am trying to add permission handler to my flutter application but when I click the button it gives me absolutely no response at all on the device(it is not showing the dialog for requesting permission). I tried to make another project and do the same thing there it worked fine there.
Restarted application in 1,738ms.
E/flutter (20650): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview
E/flutter (20650):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:513)
E/flutter (20650):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createForPlatformViewLayer(PlatformViewsController.java:169)
E/flutter (20650):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:105)
E/flutter (20650):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:55)
E/flutter (20650):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
E/flutter (20650):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
E/flutter (20650):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/flutter (20650):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (20650):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
E/flutter (20650):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/flutter (20650):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:224)
E/flutter (20650):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:318)
E/flutter (20650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8727)
E/flutter (20650):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (20650):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:561)
E/flutter (20650):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
E/flutter (20650): , null, null)
E/flutter (20650): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
E/flutter (20650): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
E/flutter (20650): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20650): #2      ExpensiveAndroidViewController._sendCreateMessage (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:1115:5)
E/flutter (20650): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20650): #3      AndroidViewController.create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:838:5)
E/flutter (20650): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20650):
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher(20650): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher(20650): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
E/flutter (20650): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method requestPermissions on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)
E/flutter (20650): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:7)
E/flutter (20650): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20650): #1      MethodChannelPermissionHandler.requestPermissions (package:permission_handler_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_permission_handler.dart:80:9)
E/flutter (20650): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20650): #2      PermissionActions.request (package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart:109:10)
E/flutter (20650): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20650): #3      _ShopsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:pos/screens/Shops/shops.dart:83:23)
E/flutter (20650): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20650):

This is the file in which I am applying the permission handler
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pos/Screens/OtherPages/new_shop_form.dart';
import 'package:pos/Screens/OtherPages/shop_management_screen.dart';
import 'package:pos/constants.dart';
import 'package:pos/labels.dart';
import 'package:pos/CommonWidgets/button.dart';
import 'package:pos/screens/LoginSignupScreens/SignUp/page_view.dart';
import 'package:pos/screens/LoginSignupScreens/login.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class Shops extends StatefulWidget {
  const Shops({super.key});

  @override
  _ShopsState createState() => _ShopsState();
}

class _ShopsState extends State<Shops> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.volume_up),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/backgrounds/bg_image3.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(),
              const ImageIcon(
                AssetImage('assets/images/shop.png'),
                size: 130,
                color: kTextColor,
              ),
              Text(
                Labels.shop(),
                style: const TextStyle(color: kTextColor, fontSize: 24),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 40),
              LanguageButton(
                text: Labels.addShop(),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const Newformshop(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                borderColor: kBorderColor1,
                textColor: kTextColor,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                height: 70,
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderRadius: 100,
                textSize: 26,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              LanguageButton(
                text: Labels.shop(),
                onTap: () async {
                  // Navigator.push(
                  //   context,
                  //   MaterialPageRoute(
                  //     builder: (context) => const ShopManagementScreen(),
                  //   ),
                  // );
                  PermissionStatus cameraStatus =
                      await Permission.camera.request();
                  print('Camera permission status: $cameraStatus');

                  if (cameraStatus.isGranted) {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const ShopManagementScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (cameraStatus.isDenied) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      const SnackBar(content: Text("Camera permission denied")),
                    );
                  } else if (cameraStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      const SnackBar(
                          content:
                              Text("Camera permission permanently denied")),
                    );
                    await openAppSettings(); // Open app settings
                  }
                },
                borderColor: kBorderColor1,
                textColor: kTextColor,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                height: 70,
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderRadius: 100,
                textSize: 26,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              LanguageButton(
                text: 'LOL1',
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const Login(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                borderColor: kBorderColor1,
                textColor: kTextColor,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                height: 70,
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderRadius: 100,
                textSize: 26,
              ),
              LanguageButton(
                text: 'LOL2',
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MultiStepForm(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                borderColor: kBorderColor1,
                textColor: kTextColor,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                height: 70,
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderRadius: 100,
                textSize: 26,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is the Android.xml file
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pos">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:label="pos"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
                
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

Dependencies:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  # flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0
  youtube_player_flutter: ^9.0.1
  simple_barcode_scanner: ^0.0.8
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
  mobile_scanner: ^5.0.1
  camera: ^0.10.5+9
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1

Flutter doctor:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.2538], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.34)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.89.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

I tried to make another project and do the same thing there it worked fine there. I also tried running flutter clean and building it again didn't work:(

you are using permission handler wrong, this is how you get the current status of permission
   PermissionStatus cameraStatus =
                  await Permission.camera.status;

then check if permission is granted or not, if the permission is not permanently denied, then you can request using
  status = await Permission.camera.request();

this is a sample usage in my code
    var status = await Permission.camera.status;
    if (status.isGranted) {
      //do something
    }
    if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Camera permission permanently denied'),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      status = await Permission.camera.request();
      if (status.isGranted) {
       
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Camera permission granted'),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Camera permission denied'),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  



Well, I also find myself having problems regarding the use and management of the package permission_handler: ^11.3.1
In my project I must know if the user is connected (or not) to the Wi-Fi network, 4G, etc.

Well, it has offline functions that, depending on the connection, initiate the download, consult or establish a data usage limit. (at least that's the idea).
The 'problem' appears when I want to know the status of the permit to know whether to apply for it or not and blah blah.
But due to the lack of documentation about the package, I don't know if it is, exists or supported and in what way, circumstance or context.

When I open the tree, nothing even similar Network, Wifi or anything similar appears.

So I don't even know where to start, because when the app starts up, it must know the network status in order to configure itself.
If anyone please has access to documentation, I would appreciate it if you would share it with me.
Respond my self [For the record]:

For both Android and iOS it is not required to explicitly request permission to access the internet. Therefore the internet (or network) connectivity level or status is not considered a feature that concerns the permission_handler.

Instead use connectivity_plus plugin.
Citation:That's what the  of permission_handler answered to me.
ScreenShot of options 1 and
ScreenShot of options 2

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
